Forecasting positive time series with missing values and few observations
I am working on forecasting a positive time series dataset of prices with missing values and only a limited number of observations. Specifically, I have 150 observations, one per week, and I need to forecast prices for the next 70 weeks.
The challenge I face is twofold: dealing with missing values and ensuring the reliability of my forecasts. Given the limited data points and the presence of missing values, what are the best statistical methods or techniques I can employ for accurate forecasting of prices?
Additionally, I would like to determine the minimum number of simulations of forecasts required to guarantee a 95% confidence level that my forecasts are close to the true price curve. Is there a method or formula I can use to calculate this?
Any insights or recommendations, especially tailored to price forecasting, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I would suggest you start with a State-Space model that allows for latent temporal processes to evolve through time, irrespective of whether or not observations occurred in that timepoint. This kind of model is the backbone of models that the {mvgam} R package constructs and estimates. This kind of model works because the package relies on Bayesian inference with Hamiltonian Monte Carlo sampling, using the 'Stan' interface. You can learn a bit more about how it works from this introductory webinar and from the package vignettes, particularly the State-Space vignette.
With non-negative, continuous observtions you may want to start with a Gamma or Lognormal observation model.
